# Rails devise simple_form for signup doesn't validate before saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, simple-form

I have a devise user signup using simple_form and I'm facing 2 issues:

#### Issue 1:

If I donot add '@ or .' in email, a validation message is flashed when I press signup, to conform to the email format and also when giving this validation message the url is still /user/signup.

But for other fields - password and username where there's a length validate message, it doesn't display the same message to conform username between 4...20 characters or for password length. Also url changes to /users and because the user is still not created so if I reload that url from browser, it gives a 500 error.

What should I do to have validation message displayed and yet url is not changed? Thanks.

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= f.input :email, required: '*', autofocus: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Email', input_html: { class: 'input-md form-control' } %>
    <%= f.input :username, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'User Name', input_html: { class: 'input-md form-control' } %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Password', input_html: { class: 'input-md form-control' } %>

    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign-Up" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Customised devise registrations controller:

```
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
    if !User.exists?(email: resource.email)
      #to validate form before creating user 
      resource.valid? #first check if validation is successful
      resource.errors.messages.except!(:password) #remove password from errors
      if resource.save
         redirect_to root_path, alert: "new user created"
      else
         #render root_path, alert: "There's a problem saving your profile to the Database!"
       end
     end
   end
```

end

#### Issue 2:

It is with registrations controller code above `resource.valid?` must validate and only after that goto save but it doesn't validate...why? So, flow comes to save and I've to comment 'else' part otherwise it does not display any validation message. But commenting 'else part of resource.save' is not recommended.

Comment: Issue 2: when you say "but it doesn't validate...", do you mean it does not run statement `resource.valid?` OR the statement does not add any errors to resource after this statement?

Comment: In `else` part, try `render :new`.